# Pivot query Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have the below table and I am trying to write an Oracle select query that would result in the second table.

I understand I have to use Pivot but I can't figure at all how to do.

| MSGID | KEY | COLVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | height | 18 |
| 15 | length | 19 |
| 15 | width | 20 |
| 15 | notImportant | xxx |
| 16 | height | 21 |
| 16 | length | 22 |
| 16 | width | 23 |
| 16 | notImportant | xxx |
| 17 | height | 24 |
| 17 | length | 25 |
| 17 | width | 26 |
| 17 | notImportant | xx |

Desired result:

| MsgID | height | length | width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 16 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 17 | 24 | 25 | 26 |

Tried the below code but without success....

```
select MSGID, HEIGHT, LENGTH, WIDTH
     
  from (select MSGID, KEY, COLVALUE              
           from table ) 
  PIVOT
(
    max(COLVALUE)
    FOR KEY IN ('HEIGHT','LENGTH','WIDTH')
)
```

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> select msgid,
  2    max(case when key = 'height' then colvalue end) height,
  3    max(case when key = 'length' then colvalue end) length,
  4    max(case when key = 'width'  then colvalue end) width
  5  from test
  6  group by msgid
  7  order by msgid;

     MSGID HEIGHT     LENGTH     WIDTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        15 18         19         20
        16 21         22         23
        17 24         25         26

SQL>
```

Or, with `pivot`:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  pivot
  4    (max(COLVALUE)
  5     FOR KEY IN ('height','length','width')
  6    )
  7  order by 1;

     MSGID 'he 'le 'wi
---------- --- --- ---
        15 18  19  20
        16 21  22  23
        17 24  25  26

SQL>
```

Comment: Wow! I was so close... The pivot query worked like a charm! Thanks!!